# Out-Of-Proc Exe Server

Tags: vb.net

I am using the example code for creating an ActiveX-Exe COM server in VB.Net:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/VBExeCOMServer-74ecdb1c

When I call the GetCurrentProcessID from within the Active-X-Exe, it returns the same ID as the calling application.

Can somebody tell me if that is natural or whether I did something wrong in encapsulating the ActiveX-Exe component?

I am testing it like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    _MouseIndicator = New twsMouseIndicator.clsMouseIndicator
    With _MouseIndicator
        .ImagePath = "d:\dev\projects\osc\gui\autoclick\prog4.png"
        .Size = 300
        .Alpha = 155
        .FollowMouse = True
        .Active = True
    End With

    Dim iProcessIDOutOfProcID As Integer = _MouseIndicator.CurrentProcessID
    Dim iCallerProcessID As Integer = GetCurrentProcessId()

    If iProcessIDOutOfProcID = iCallerProcessID Then
        MessageBox.Show("ProcIDs are the same, namely " & iCallerProcessID & ". This can not be right!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Everything is okay.")
    End If

End Sub
```

In the calling application "GetCurrentProcessID" is declared as

```
Module Module1
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get current process ID.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Public Function GetCurrentProcessId() As UInt32
    End Function

End Module
```

In the Out-Of-Proc-COM-Server, it is declared like this:

```
Public Function CurrentProcessID() As UInt32

    Return NativeMethod.GetCurrentProcessId

End Function

 Friend Class NativeMethod

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get current process ID.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Friend Shared Function GetCurrentProcessId() As UInt32
    End Function
```

Comment: You _are_ calling `GetCurrentProcessID` and not `GetCurrentProcess`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes.     Friend Shared Function GetCurrentProcessId() As UInt32

Comment: you probably need to show the code you added to expose the process id and how you compare them because it *Works on My System* http://i.imgur.com/5fO51vz.png

Comment: I have edited my posting and added some code.

Comment: I think you messed something up when you converted the MSDN `SimpleObject` class to your `twsMouseIndicator.clsMouseIndicator`.  I did *mostly* the same thing as you, except using a module.  To test if the COM Server is reporting the correct ID, open task manager and see if the PID reported matches the one in TaskManager.  In my case, the NET form of getting PID, the API version and TaskManager all agree.

Comment: Without seeing `twsMouseIndicator.clsMouseIndicator` does it is hard to tell. However, what you are describing sounds as if somehow you created an in process server (local DLL instead of an EXE). If a COM object is inproc it runs in the same address space of the client (and would report the same processid). The other possibility is somehow `GetCurrentProcessId()` is making a local call on the client side instead of doing it through the COM object. I think without further code this is hard to diagnose.

Comment: And I guess the final scenario is that the way you have set up the client code you are adding the com class (the .vb file) directly to your client project and instantiating it directly. If you do that it is simply a local class that happens to also work as a COM object. A local class would be just like any class running in your process.

Comment: One experiment you should try is this. Replace `_MouseIndicator = New twsMouseIndicator.clsMouseIndicator` with `Dim MouseIndicator as Object` followed by `MouseIndicator = CreateObject("VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject")` . If you changed the name of the server and the object name then replace `VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject` with what you used (this is the `Progid`). Then in the rest of `Button1_Click` replace `_MouseIndicator` with `MouseIndicator` . This experiment sees if you can create the remote object via Interop/COM.

Comment: @Plutonix When you call the COM server, does it expose the same ProcessID as the calling application? I have tried it with the MSDN example, and both the "SimpleComObject" and the calling application return the same CurrentProcessID. Due to the nature of Out-Of-Proc apps, this should not be right. Do you agree?

Comment: @MichaelPetch No, I cannot create the object via InterOp. VS simply does hang in the line "... = CreateObject(...". No error message or whatsoever.

Comment: I have uploaded an example project here: http://www.file-upload.net/download-9604388/outofproc.zip.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that works in my development environment. I took the OP's example project from [here](http://file-upload.net/download-9604388/outofproc.zip.html) that was referenced in a comment. I have created a **new** [outofproc.zip](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/outofproc.zip) that I hope works for the OP. Some history of what I found and learned along the way follows.

I rebuilt the `VBExeComServer` project (which installed and registered the `COM` executable). I tried to use the OP's `caller` project with my method of instantiating a `SimpleObject` via `CreateObject("VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject")` and it hung the same way the OP described in a comment. I found that puzzling.

I then decided to look at the `VBExeComServer` project more thoroughly. It is basically the same sample one the OP posted in his question. Since this project is known to work it was likely something environmental. After some trial and error and a few Google searches I found this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303814/com-cannot-start-out-of-process-net-server-compiled-as-anycpu). Although this question didn't get an answer I felt the information provided seemed somewhat similar to what I was experiencing. In particular it says:

> I am trying to get COM to start my out-of-process .NET COM server. It works if the server process is **compiled with x64**, but if I use **AnyCPU** (which is what I want) then it **hangs for a while** and eventually fails with 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE). How can I get this to work?

I found the `hangs for a while` comment rather similar to what we are seeing. I got the same error they did when I tried to use Powershell to instantiate the object too. Although indications are he didn't get it to work I felt there was enough to investigate the settings of our project. First off `VBExeComServer` was using **Any CPU** as a platform type. Given the excerpt above I decided to amend the project creating 'x64' and 'x86' platform options via the configuration manager. Then I tried to build the **x64** it failed to register the executable and build a type library. I tried **x86** and it compiled/registered. I found this [Microsoft Article](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/956933) regarding x64 assemblies that got me on the right track. In particular it had these instructions:

> To work around the problem, add a post build command to call the 64-bit version of RegAsm.exe using the following steps.
>
> 1. In the **project properties**, select **“Build Events…”** from the **Compile page**.
> 2. Add the following **post build command line**
>    "%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\regasm" "$(TargetPath)"

I didn't use what they recommended since it would limit the project to only building x64. I decided to enhance this idea by looking at the build platform type. If it was x64 I would use the `Framework64` regasm as above. Unfortunately, the `VBExeComServer` project (made by MS) assumed 32-bit assemblies by default not 64-bit since they used 32-bit `regasm` in the post build event. I ended up using this for the `post-build events`:

```
echo Generate and register type library.
if "$(PlatformName)" == "x64" (
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe /tlb "$(TargetPath)"
) else  (
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe /tlb "$(TargetPath)"
)
echo Register the component.
if "$(PlatformName)" == "x64" (
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe "$(TargetPath)"
) else (
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe "$(TargetPath)"
)
echo Generate and register type library.
```

I then tried building for platform `Any CPU`, and it compiled and registered properly. I then did `x86` and then `x64` builds. All of them built and registered as expected. Please note when building COM servers I run Visual Studio as **administrator** so that the process of COM registration has proper permissions to update the registry system wide.

Next I went into task manager (and this is important). I killed off all the old VBExeComServer processes that may have been laying around. One could resort to restarting windows to make sure. Failure to clean up old executables from memory could lead to undefined behavior.

So now does the `caller` (client) code work? I loaded the project up and it ran fine. I even modified the `caller` project to be built as `x86`, `x64` and `Any CPU` platforms, and they worked. All of them found a `processid` of the `SimpleObject` that was not equal to that of the client process.

**Special note:** If you want the `caller` project to work and you use platform type `Any CPU` on a 64-bit system, or use platform type `x64` you will need to make sure you build a 64-bit `VBExeComServer` as above. Failure to do this will result in the hangs we experienced.

Next I restored the OP's *early binding* code:

```
Private _Com As VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject
_Com = New VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject
```

I had a hunch this would not load the out-of-proc-server via COM/Interop. I was right. When I restored these lines I was able to run the `caller` program but the `Process IDs` were the same. The reason for this is that the VB.Net COM object is created as an assembly that happens to provide an out of process COM Server. However if you try to import the EXE as a reference (or the TLB) it will tell you that you can't do it that way because it is a CLR assembly. When you do `_Com As VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject` VB.Net will bypass all the COM/Interop code and add that executable as an assembly with direct access to the objects natively.

Someone else may have an idea how to make this work another way. The following uses *late binding*:

```
Private _Com As Object
_Com = CreateObject("VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject")
```

`CreateObject` forces creation of `VBExeCOMServer.SimpleObject` through COM/Interop. If it isn't already running our COM out-of-proc server will be launched. Once a server is running to handle our request a new `SimpleObject` will be instantiated.

My `outofproc.zip` file referenced earlier has been amended with all the items mentioned above. At least in my environment it does work as expected.

Comment: Oh wow, what an amazing description, thank you! Your solution works on my system. I am glad you discovered that late binding is the only solution. I would never have thought of that.