# how can I stream Live data from java code to excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have live data from API that changes every minuet, I have to write this data to excel file using java how can I do this? for a use-case lets say I have a time watch that changes every second and I want the time to display in Excel file every second, also the file created will be only read only? can I use this time cell value and make any calculations in another sheet (while current sheet being opened)?

Comment: Try to do some research about Java Rx , that may be help you to handle the data streaming. After that you can look for how write data in Excel file using APOI api

Comment: "and I want the time to display in Excel file every second": Not possible using `apache poi` as `apache poi` only creates files. It does not interact with `Excel`'s `GUI`. But exactly this would be necessary to do someting like this. If `Excel` opens a file in it's `GUI` then it parses that file and after that it do not react to changes to that file from outside `GUI`.

Comment: Any other library?

Comment: Apache POI is the wrong approach. A simple approach is to write a few lines of VBA code to parse a text file or to consume a web service. A more elaborated approach would be to provide your own OLE container/object which is able to trigger an Excel refresh on new data.

Comment: VBA may not work in current project setup, can you please explain or provide link how can I  achieve OLE container/obj ?

Comment: An ole container is basically a ActiveX (or similar) object (= a .dll library) which needs to be registered on the machine running Excel. I haven't yet written myself such an OLE object, but use one to get PLC / machine data. Please explain why a static Excel file, which can be further secured via a custom signature, is not feasible in your setup ... i.e. just because it's easy with POI to generate Excel files, this doesn't mean that's the hammer for all nails

Comment: If you are really that adventures and keen to get your hands dirty with MS COM hell, have a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983730/out-of-proc-exe-server) - the links are stale, but I think you can google the sources

Comment: @kiwiwings no VBA , leave the POI part aside I just want a way to write data to a opened xlsx file and that data refreshes continuously any way that I can do from JAVA, similar feature is available in xlwings python library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232123/discussion-between-kiwiwings-and-vh1ne).